# I am trying to show floating activity and it is working but the problem appears on less than API 24

Tags: floating

```
2021-08-10 10:21:03.685 4272-4288/com.hamid.almusabaha E/libEGL: load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
2021-08-10 10:21:05.530 4272-4272/com.hamid.almusabaha E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gms.chimera
2021-08-10 10:21:06.564 4272-4343/com.hamid.almusabaha E/libEGL: validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
2021-08-10 10:21:06.570 4272-4332/com.hamid.almusabaha E/cr_SBApiBridge: Failed to init handler: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.reflect.Constructor java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(java.lang.Class[])' on a null object reference
2021-08-10 10:21:11.302 4272-4272/com.hamid.almusabaha E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.hamid.almusabaha, PID: 4272
    android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:679)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:342)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:93)
        at com.hamid.almusabaha.Musbiha_Large$7.run(Musbiha_Large.java:185)
        at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:5866)
        at com.hamid.almusabaha.Musbiha_Large.showFloatView(Musbiha_Large.java:179)
        at com.hamid.almusabaha.MainActivity$20.onClick(MainActivity.java:318)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my activity

```
public class Musbiha_Large {

    private static boolean mIsFloatViewShowing;

    private Activity mActivity;
    private WindowManager mWindowManager;
    private View mFloatView;
    private WindowManager.LayoutParams mFloatViewLayoutParams;
    private boolean mFloatViewTouchConsumedByMove = false;
    private int mFloatViewLastX;
    private int mFloatViewLastY;
    private int mFloatViewFirstX;
    private int mFloatViewFirstY;
    static   LinearLayout coverLargeL;

     private int numpr = 0;
    boolean isDark = false;
    boolean isPha = false;

     public
     Musbiha_Large(final Activity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
        mFloatView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.musbiha_large, null);
         final TextView   textNbrLarge = mFloatView. findViewById (  R.id.textNbrLarge );
         final ImageView  PlayLarge = mFloatView. findViewById (  R.id.PlayLarge );
         final  ImageView  lightLarge = mFloatView. findViewById (  R.id.lightLarge );
         final    ImageView  ResetLarge = mFloatView. findViewById (  R.id.ResetLarge );
         final LinearLayout  lirarlightLarge = mFloatView. findViewById (  R.id.lirarlightLarge );
         final  ImageButton exetLarge = mFloatView.findViewById(R.id.exetLarge);
         final   ImageButton plph = mFloatView.findViewById(R.id.plph);

         coverLargeL = mFloatView.findViewById(R.id.
coverLargeF);

  
     



        exetLarge.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismissFloatView();
            }
        });

        mFloatView.setOnClickListener(mFloatViewOnClickListener);
        mFloatView.setOnTouchListener(mFloatViewOnTouchListener);

        mFloatViewLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        mFloatViewLayoutParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
        mFloatViewLayoutParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;

        mFloatViewLayoutParams.type = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O
                ? WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
                : WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST;

        mFloatViewLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        mFloatViewLayoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        mFloatViewLayoutParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

    }



    public void dismissFloatView() {
        if (mIsFloatViewShowing) {
            mIsFloatViewShowing = false;
            mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (mWindowManager != null) {
                        mWindowManager.removeViewImmediate(mFloatView);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void showFloatView() {
        if (!mIsFloatViewShowing) {
            mIsFloatViewShowing = true;
            mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (!mActivity.isFinishing()) {
                        mWindowManager = (WindowManager) mActivity.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
                        if (mWindowManager != null) {
                            mWindowManager.addView(mFloatView, mFloatViewLayoutParams);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

     private View.OnClickListener mFloatViewOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                  //  Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Float view is clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              //    sbha.setBackgroundResource ( R.drawable.green );

                }
            });
        }
    };

     private View.OnTouchListener mFloatViewOnTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {

         @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO)
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            WindowManager.LayoutParams prm = mFloatViewLayoutParams;
            int totalDeltaX = mFloatViewLastX - mFloatViewFirstX;
            int totalDeltaY = mFloatViewLastY - mFloatViewFirstY;

            switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    mFloatViewLastX = (int) event.getRawX();
                    mFloatViewLastY = (int) event.getRawY();
                    mFloatViewFirstX = mFloatViewLastX;
                    mFloatViewFirstY = mFloatViewLastY;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    int deltaX = (int) event.getRawX() - mFloatViewLastX;
                    int deltaY = (int) event.getRawY() - mFloatViewLastY;
                    mFloatViewLastX = (int) event.getRawX();
                    mFloatViewLastY = (int) event.getRawY();
                    if (Math.abs(totalDeltaX) >= 5 || Math.abs(totalDeltaY) >= 5) {
                        if (event.getPointerCount() == 1) {
                            prm.x += deltaX;
                            prm.y += deltaY;
                            mFloatViewTouchConsumedByMove = true;
                            if (mWindowManager != null) {
                                mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(mFloatView, prm);
                            }
                        } else {
                            mFloatViewTouchConsumedByMove = false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        mFloatViewTouchConsumedByMove = false;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return mFloatViewTouchConsumedByMove;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Have you found the solution? Because I'm facing the same problem